# How to move two 32 bit registers in to one 64 bit?

Tags: assembly, x86, move, x86-64

Let's say that I want to put two 32 bit registers `EAX` as low 32 bit word and `EDX` as high 32 bit word into `RAX`.
I have found one way:

```
shl   rdx, 32
or    rax, rdx
```

This method works only if we are sure that bits from 32 to 61 of `RAX` are 0. If we are not sure about that, then we must first clear the high 32 bit word, like:

```
mov   eax, eax      //This instruction should clear the high 32 bit word of RAX
```

Is this the shortest way?

Is there a single asm x86-64 instruction that does this operation?

Comment: AFAIK there is nothing shorter. If the target register is a xmm regsiter, you could use two `pinsd` instructions and avoid the clearing instruction.

Comment: @drhirsch: I have check almost all Intel documentation and I didn't find anything usefull. :)

Comment: Yeah, you might be able to save a little space with a "xor eax, eax" to clear it, but that seems about as short as it can be.

Comment: @Nicholas Hembree: No, under x86-64 the instruction `xor eax, eax` clears whole `RAX` register!

Comment: Shouldn't that be mov rax, eax?

Comment: @BlackBear: That should be nice! But unfortunately there is no such instruction!

Comment: @GJ Oops! You're right, must have been a lack of coffee moment, don't know what I was thinking there... =) Thanks!

Comment: @hirschhornsalz: if the target is an xmm register, use `movd xmm0, eax` / `pinsrd xmm0, edx, 1`.  Using 2x `pinsrd` is slower and has a false dependency on the old value of `xmm0`, but `movd` moves with zero-extension to the rest of the register.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Perhaps this is a tad better:

```
shl     rax,32
shrd    rax,rdx,32
```

Does not assume that high dwords are zero.

Comment: That was the combination I was searching for. I knew it had to be a `shrd` or `shld`