# zero out top 32 bits of 64-bit register

Tags: assembly, x86-64, machine-code

Using amd64 assembly, whats the best way to zero out the top 32 bits of a 64-bit register, e.g. zero out the bits of rax that are not covered by eax?  It appears that I cannot and the whole register against a 64-bit constant.

Comment: isn't eax the lower 32 bits of rax?  see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580838/how-to-move-two-32-bit-registers-in-to-one-64-bit

Comment: If eax is a signed value then you want 1s if the value is negative, not 0s.  MOVSXD.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`movl %eax, %eax` or `mov eax, eax`, depending on the assembler in use.

see: Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures - Software Developer’s Manual, [Volume 1](http://www.intel.com.au/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-1-manual.pdf), 3.4.1.1 :   General-Purpose Registers in 64-Bit Mode.

**32-bit operands generate a 32-bit result, zero-extended to a 64-bit result in the destination general-purpose 
register.**

I should also add, in regards to @HansPassant's comment: 7.3.1.7 :

**The MOVSXD instruction operates on 64-bit data. It sign-extends a 32-bit value to 64 bits.**

Comment: It's always better to **`mov` to a *different* register, if possible** (without spending extra instructions elsewhere).  `mov same,same` defeats mov-elimination on Intel SnB-family and AMD Ryzen, so `mov edi,edi` costs 1c of latency vs. `mov ecx,edi` costing 0 cycles as part of a dep chain.  (See [Can x86's MOV really be "free"? Why can't I reproduce this at all?](//stackoverflow.com/q/44169342)).  Even if latency is more important than throughput, a back-to-back `mov eax, edi` / `mov edi, eax` might defeat mov-elimination for one of them, so generally don't do that.