# 80386 - How does the cpu choose between movzbw and movzbl

Tags: assembly, x86

The opcodes for both *movzbw* and *movzbl* are `OF B6`. I don't understand how they can be distinguished by observing the *ModR/M* byte. From the [Intel 80386 Programmer's Reference Manual (1986)](http://www.logix.cz/michal/doc/i386/chp17-m3.htm#17-03-MOVZX):

> ```
> MOVZX  ── Move with Zero-Extend
>
> Opcode    Instruction      Clocks   Description
> 0F B6 /r  MOVZX r16,r/m8   3/6       Move byte to word with zero-extend
> 0F B6 /r  MOVZX r32,r/m8   3/6       Move byte to dword, zero-extend
> 0F B7 /r  MOVZX r32,r/m16  3/6       Move word to dword, zero-extend
> ```

How does the processor distinguish between and *movzbw* and *movzbl*?

Comment: As an addendum to the answers here, the 386 Reference Manual has a section about the operand and address size prefixes. http://www.logix.cz/michal/doc/i386/chp17-01.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it uses a prefix byte:

```
66 0f b6 c0             movzx  ax,al
0f b6 c0                movzx  eax,al
0f b7 c0                movzx  eax,ax
```

Edit: note, in 64-bit mode, the above is the same but there is another prefix:

```
48 0f b6 c0             movzx  rax,al
48 0f b7 c0             movzx  rax,ax
```

Note that there is no `movzx  rax, eax` instruction.

(I'm an utter novice at this so I can't explain exactly why, I just throw code at the compiler and see if it's accepted).

Comment: because most operations on 32-bit register zero out the top 32 bits, therefore `movzx rax, eax` is not necessary. `mov eax, eax`, `and eax, eax`, `or eax, eax`... would do the trick. [Why do most x64 instructions zero the upper part of a 32 bit register](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11177137/995714), [zero out top 32 bits of 64-bit register](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21439289/995714)

Comment: There's a `movsx r64, r/m32`, but another new opcode for `movzx r64, r32` would be a waste of limited opcode space that could be used instead for new extensions.  `mov r32, r/m32` already does the job.  (mov is a better choice than an ALU op, for Intel and AMD.)  Using a REX prefix just for REX.W=1 is a waste of space for 8-64 and 16->64, too.  An assembler that was more aggressive about using the shortest encoding for what you wrote might leave out the REX prefix for `movxz rax, dl`, like how `mov eax, [rsi + 0]` is encoded with no displacement byte (same as if you actually wrote `[rsi]`).

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the operand size prefix, 66H. It toggles the operand size between 16 and 32 bits.